# Help including time in a resources optimization problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am struggling to formulate the following problem as (potentially) a linear programming optimization problem;

Imagine that I want to optimize the dispatch ($Power_{m, h}$) of a set of motors in hourly steps, while keeping a constraint in the time the motor is used ($t_{m, max}$).

Let's assume that the dispatch of the motor power each hour has a price ($Price_{m, h}$).

So far I have done:

$$
f_{min}: \sum_{h=1}^{24}\sum_{m}^{motors}{Power_{m,h} · Price_{m,h}}
$$
s.t.

$P_{min} <= Power_{m,h} <= P_{max}, \forall h \in \{1...24\}, m \in \{motors\}$

If a motor is dispatched in an hour $h$, then I should account for that hour, wether if the motor is not dispatched in a particular hour I must not account for that hour.

The time is dependent of the power value in a binary form.

**How can I express the time usage restriction?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want binary variables $y_{mh}$ that take value $1$ if and only if motor $m$ is used during hour $h$.

Don't forget to link them with variables $Power_{mh}$ by adding the constraints:
$$
Power_{mh} \le P_{max} y_{mh}
$$

(this ensures that when $Power_{mh}$ is positive, $y_{mh}$ is activated)

Comment: shall I include $y_{mh}$ in the objective function as well?

Comment: If you have a fixed cost per motor per hour, then yes.